# Click Event Shows And Removes All Overlays Instead Of Individually - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach, onclick, dom-events

I have a wrapper container where I would like is so when I click on the name each piece of info shows just for that wrapper and when I click/close the 'x' button it only removes it for that button.

Using the `forEach()` method it is showing and removing all of the inner containers except for just the ones that have been clicked.

I thought it might be possible doing with the `this` keyword but I couldn't get it to work.

I'm new to Javascript so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anna_paul/pen/JjWPLjx

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  
  let name = document.querySelectorAll('.name')
  let close = document.querySelectorAll('.close')
  let innerText = document.querySelectorAll('.inner-text')

  // ----- show text
  name.forEach(function(item){

      item.addEventListener('click', function(){

          innerText.forEach(function(inner){
              inner.classList.add('active')
          })

      }, false)

  })

  // ---- hide text
  close.forEach(function(item){

      item.addEventListener('click', function(){

          innerText.forEach(function(inner){
             inner.classList.remove('active')
          })

      }, false)

  })
  
}) // DomContentLoaded
```

```css
* {position: relative; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 10rem;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.inner-text {
  background: red;
  display:none;
}

.inner-text.active {
    display: block
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5rem;
    right: 0rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.name {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="name">Name</p>
  <div>Other content</div>
  <div class="inner-text">
    <div class="close">x</div>
    <ul>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="name">Name</p>
  <div>Other content</div>
  <div class="inner-text">
    <div class="close">x</div>
    <ul>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
      <li>INFO</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much identified the issue in your question which is that you are looping over all the panels in your event handlers and adding/removing classes to all the panels. Instead, you can work with "event delegation" where you set up just one event handler at a common ancestor of all the panels and let the event "bubble" up to that ancestor and be handled there. Also, because the code for the show and the hide are so similar, you can just have one function for both.

Lastly, `innerText` is not a great name for a variable as `innerText` is actually a DOM element property name.

```js
// If you place the script that holds this code just before the
// closing BODY tag, you won't need to set up a DOMContentLoaded
// event.

document.querySelector(".masterWrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Check to see if the event originated at an element
  // we care about handling
  
  // Get a reference to the <div class="wrapper"> ancestor of the clicked element
  // and then find the <div class="inner-text"> descedant within it.
  const inner_text = event.target.closest(".wrapper").querySelector(".inner-text");
  
  // When Name is clicked
  if(event.target.classList.contains("name")){
    // If the panel is not already showing its content:
    if(!inner_text.classList.contains("active")){
      inner_text.classList.add("active");
    }
  }
  
  // When the X is clicked
  if(event.target.classList.contains("close")){
      event.target.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
  }  

});
```

```css
* {position: relative; box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 10rem;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.inner-text {
  background: red;
  display:none;
}

.inner-text.active {
    display: block
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5rem;
    right: 0rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

.name {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="masterWrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="name">Name</p>
    <div>Other content</div>
    <div class="inner-text">
      <div class="close">x</div>
      <ul>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="name">Name</p>
    <div>Other content</div>
    <div class="inner-text">
      <div class="close">x</div>
      <ul>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus I think I might need to edit the question. I simplified the mark up to make it easier to read, but it won't be a sibling element on the full version. I'll need to do it referencing the variable names. I though 'this' might work but can't get it to play ball.

Comment: @Anna_p It doesn’t have to be a sibling. No matter what the relationship, there’s a way to reference it without id’s or explicit references. Just edit your question to show the true hierarchy.

Comment: If I add the full code in there is no way anyone will answer the question: it's a site I've taken over and it has about 10 layers deep of truly pointless html. I just need to find of way inside each individaul 'wrapper' element when the name is clicked for that wrapper, the innertext shows and when the 'close' element is clicked inside that individual wrapper it is removed. I thought I could do this purely by referencing the variable names?

Comment: I've edited the question though to make it clearer.

Comment: @Anna_p Although the HTML layers may be complex, you really should show an example of how at least one of them is structured. I really don't know what you mean by *referencing the variable names* since a variable still has to be set to an element.

Comment: Actually I added another div in that sits inbetween the 'name' and 'inner-text' elements. On the site this div is huge and full of child elements, but I don't need to add of all those. The current HTML should be enough so that any solution to it should work on the site. I do appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: @Anna_p Answer updated. As I said, it really doesn't matter how complex the HTML structure is, there is always a way to get a reference to the part of it you want in a relative way instead of a static identifier. The comments explain how I'm finding the appropriate element.

Comment: Thanks a million @ScottMarcus that now works a treat.